# Removing an item from an array by name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function to remove an item from an array by name. The code keeps removing the first item in the array (index 0) despite passing in arr.indexOf(i)

```js
let fruits = [apples, oranges, grapes, bananas]

function removeFlavorByName(arr, string){
    let placeHolder;
    for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i]==string){
           placeHolder = arr.indexOf(i)
       }
    }
    arr.splice(placeHolder,1);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` has a capital O

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it but same error. It seems to think to always return 0 for the indexOf

Comment: That is not the same error. If it returns 0, it means now you don't get "arr.indexof is not a function". The very first line of your code references variables which you have not declared.

Comment: Your array should contain string values in your example: let fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas"];

Comment: My array has strings. I just wrote it in a hurry above but in the code it does have "apples" etc. I did declare the only variable which is placeHolder to store the index of the string in the array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify your code, here is that same function cleaned up. Since you are using `indexOf` you don't need the loop.

```js
fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas"]

function removeFlavorByName(arr, string) {
  index = arr.indexOf(string);
  arr.splice(index, 1)
  return arr
}

console.log(removeFlavorByName(fruits, "apples"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution simpler and more compact is using the *filter* built-in method.

```js
fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas"]

const removeFlavor = (arr, string) => arr.filter((item) => item != string)

console.log(removeFlavorByName(fruits, "apples"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a filter function.

```js
fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas"]

function removeFlavorByName(arr, string) {
  return arr.filter(fruit => fruit !== string);
}

console.log(removeFlavorByName(fruits, "apples"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data as strings in double-quotes.

```
let fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas"];

function removeFlavorByName(arr, string) {
  let newArray = arr.filter((item) => item !== string);
  return newArray;
}

console.log(removeFlavorByName(fruits, "apples"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @[imvain2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64251314/9326701) is really nice.

Just be aware that if string is not present in array, indexOf returns -1. If you use that with .splice then last item will be extracted.